# заполнение таблиц сущностей и дополнительной таблицы, реализующей их связь many to many

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Добрый день, только разбираюсь в SQL и хотелось бы понять как это должно работать.
В первой таблице items - хранятся товары магазина,
во второй таблице categories - хранятся категории этих товаров.
Существует таблица categories_has_items - в которой есть 2 внешних ключа: на таблицу товаров и таблиц категорий соответственно.
Хотелось бы понять как лучше всего вставлять новые записи о товарах.

Как при вставке информации о товаре добавить также его связь с категорией (процедура или тригер м.б.)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавить категорию
2. Добавить товар
3. Добавить связь